# Install OpenNI driver to ubuntu

Tags: ros, kinect, openni, ubuntu

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,
I am trying to install OpenNI driver to my ubuntu 11.10 but I am getting this error.
Anyone knows the solutions for this?

---

- PrimeSense OpenNI Redist    *
- ```
  2012-03-26 17:20:03       *
  ```

---

Target: Linux-x64
Version: 1.5.2.23
Num of compile jobs: 8

- Building OpenNI...
- Creating Doxygen...
  When enabling GENERATE_HTMLHELP the tree view (GENERATE_TREEVIEW) should be disabled. I'll do it for you.
  Error: unsupported character conversion for CHM_INDEX_ENCODING: 'CP1250'->'UTF-8'
  failed to execute: doxygen Doxyfile > /home/ryankoh/drivers/openni/build/openni/Platform/Linux/CreateRedist/Output/EngineDoxy.txt
  Creating Documentation Failed!
  make[1]: *** [installed] Error 1
  make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/ryankoh/drivers/openni'
  make: *** [openni_lib] Error 2

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/30508/install-openni-driver-to-ubuntu/) by [blueibeast](https://answers.ros.org/users/2055/blueibeast/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2012-03-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I recommend following the [install instructions for Ubuntu](http://www.ros.org/wiki/electric/Installation/Ubuntu) then installing the appropriate debian package such as ros-electric-openni-kinect

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2012-03-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0